# FlutterFire Firebase messaging on android works but on iOS doesn't

Tags: flutter, firebase, notifications, messaging

In my flutter project my goal is getting device token and save my database then when an action have done, sending a notification by backend.

This works in android, I can send notification to devices by flutter fire firebase messaging.

But the process doesn’t work on iOS. I get 'Request contains an invalid argument' error on backend.

I guess the token of iOS device is invalid because of the same code works on android devices.

i use flutter version 3.0.0, these packages are i used in flutter project:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.2.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.0
```

and this is how I get the token;

```
    final token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

Any suggestions?

I wanted the code that works properly for android to work in iOS simulator but it didn't work, the problem is not that the notification doesn't appear. I know that the notification doesn't appear in the simulator. the problem is that I get an error in the backend